# How do I connect to C230B contactor?

Tags: wiring, relay

I bought a contactor to wire a rely from 110V to 240V sauna heater.

[image: C230B]

What kind of connector do I need to connect to the terminal? There is no documentation at all.

Comment: Is this replacing an existing contactor in the sauna heater, or is this in some custom-built control box?

Comment: It looks like push-on lug connectors, but the picture is rather small. A clear, focused, close up picture of _your_ device showing the connections would help answer the question.